# Active customers for each day who were active in last 30 days

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a BQ table, user_events that looks like the following:

```
event_date | user_id | event_type
```

Data is for Millions of users, for different event dates.

I want to write a query that will give me a list of users for every day who were active in last 30 days.

This gives me total unique users on only that day; I can't get it to give me the last 30 for each date. Help is appreciated.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  event_date
FROM
  [TableA]
WHERE
  1=1
  AND user_id IS NOT NULL
  AND event_date >= DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -30, 'DAY')
GROUP BY
  1,
  2
ORDER BY
  2 DESC
```

Comment: what is your definition for "who were active in last 30 days"?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results so we can get an idea of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - If user have any of the event_type IN ('view','conversion','productDetail','search') , they will be considered active. That means any kind of event triggered within the app.

Comment: see my answer  - you can easily add this into solution I suggested there. will you be able to do so? or you still need help? just let know

Comment: see updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and has few assumption about your case:

1. there is only one row per date per user
2. user is considered active in last 30 days if user has at least 5 (sure can be any number - even just 1) entries/rows within those 30 days

If above make sense  - see below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id, event_date
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, event_date, 
    (COUNT(1) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
              ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(event_date) 
              RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    ) >= 5 AS activity
  FROM `yourTable`
)
WHERE activity 
GROUP BY user_id, event_date
-- ORDER BY event_date
```

If above assumption #1 is not correct  - you can just simple add pre-grouping as a sub-select

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id, event_date
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, event_date, 
    (COUNT(1) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
              ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(event_date) 
              RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    ) >= 5 AS activity
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, event_date 
    FROM `yourTable` 
    GROUP BY user_id, event_date
  )
)
WHERE activity 
GROUP BY user_id, event_date
-- ORDER BY event_date
```

**UPDATE**

> From comments: If user have any of the event_type IN ('view', 'conversion', 'productDetail', 'search') , they will be considered active. That means any kind of event triggered within the app

So, you can go with below, I think

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  user_id, event_date
FROM (
  SELECT 
    user_id, event_date, 
    (COUNT(1) 
        OVER(PARTITION BY user_id 
              ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(event_date) 
              RANGE BETWEEN 30 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
    ) >= 5 AS activity
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, event_date 
    FROM `yourTable` 
    WHERE event_type IN ('view', 'conversion', 'productDetail', 'search')
    GROUP BY user_id, event_date
  )
)
WHERE activity 
GROUP BY user_id, event_date
-- ORDER BY event_date
```

Comment: Thanks, @MikhailBerlyant let me try the updated answer.I will test out the query to see if it's giving desired results. 
When I mentioned what are active users criteria for me.I also expect the user to have min 1 row per day in 30 day period.

I need to test this logic the user is considered active in last 30 days if user has at least 5 (sure can be any number - even just 1) entries/rows within those 30 days

Comment: so you should use 30 instead of 5 :) - and note: it is BigQuery Standard SQL, so you need reference you table as \`project.dataset.yourtable\`

Comment: I am not sure why, but the moment I take event_date from the outer most query and group by clause in order to get only the list of user_id. 

My result set shrinks to half.

Comment: which makes sense as now you collapse different days for the same user into one output row per user. if you have further questions while you are walking through  your project - I really recommend you to post new question (s)

Comment: I did ask a new question. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46104930/list-of-active-customers-for-each-day-who-were-active-in-last-30-days

Comment: :o) Honestly - I didn't mean you to ask that exact question - as I think I already answered it in my previous comment. I was more referencing your real next questions :)